# Exercise analytic function g, f entire and f(g(z))=0. proof g is constant or f=0

Tags: complex-analysis

Assume f entire, D a (non-empty) domain, g:D→C is holomorphic with f(g(z))=0 for all z in D. Prove that g is constant or f≡0. 
I think this has something to do with the open-mapping theorem, but I really don't know how to prove it. Can somebody help me out?

Answer (score 1):

If $g$ is constant we are done. Otherwise, as a nonconstant function $g$ maps $D$ onto an *open* set $g(D)$. We have then that $f(w)=0$ for all $w \in g(D)$, and using the identity theorem yields...

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'if g is constant we are done'? We have to proof that either g is constant or f=0? And can I say that with the identity theorem follows that f=0 for all z in D? user1337

Comment: Can somebody help me?

Comment: @RoosJansen Either $g$ is a constant function or it is not. In the former case the proof is completed immediately. And, yes, you can say that $f=0$ in $D$.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach: the zeros of a non-zero analytic function $f$ , are isolated. If $f(g(z)==0$ in D, then the zeros of f have a limit point in $D$, and since $D$ is open and connected, it must have a limit point in $\mathbb C$.